# How to solve this limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How can I solve this: $$\lim_{x\to\infty} x\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+6x+10}}{x^2}-1\right)$$

What is the easiest method to solve it? (Without the use of Hopital)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\large{x\frac{\sqrt{x^2+6x+10}}{x^2}=\sqrt{1+\frac{6}{x}+\frac{10}{x^2}}}$

Comment: can you show me the passages?

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} x\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+6x+10}}{x^2}-1\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{1+\frac{6}{x}+\frac{10}{x^2}}-x
$$

Comment: What are the passages?

Answer (score 0):

Write your term in the form
$$\frac{1}{x}\frac{(\sqrt{x^2+6x+10}-x^2)(\sqrt{x^2+6x+10}+x^2)}{\sqrt{x^2+6x+10}+x^2}$$

Comment: This makes computing the limit much harder.

Comment: Aha, from where do you know this?

Answer (score 0):

As $x^2$ goes to $\infty$ faster than $6x$, we have that $$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+6x+10}}{x^2}\underbrace{\to}_{x\to \infty} \frac {\sqrt{x^2}}{x^2} =\frac x{x^2}=\frac1x$$
Thus 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x\left(\frac1x-1\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}1-x=-\infty$$